# index.php not working laravel 5

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have a problem in index.php. When i try to run the application i get the text of index.php in the browser.

I am using ubuntu. **I recently switched from windows** where application was working fine with xampp. Following is the screenshot of my directory structure.

[image]

Following is the .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

And following is the screenshot of index.php file in the browser.
[image]

Comment: Then there is no php on your server or it is not active.

Answer (score 1):

You have to config your apache2 to install and enable mod_php

> sudo apt-get install apache2
>
> sudo apt-get install php5
>
> sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
>
> sudo a2enmod php5
>
> sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Nothing to do with .htaccess file as it work fine, notice that it get index.php as it's intended but apache dont know how to intepret php file, hence it output as raw text.

Regards,

Comment: i followed the above but the problem still there. My PHP version is 5.5.9.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention you have to enable php by run this command `sudo a2enmod php5` and then restart apache2. Regards